# How to import a local package from different directory in Go Modules?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a project which includes 6 microservices. Every microservices are in its own directory and they are Go modules, like:

```
- user-ms
- project-ms
- messages-ms
```

There are some duplicated codes in all microservices, like mongo methods, some configs, and some structs etc. I want to merge all the duplicated codes into a package. Then, I am willing to import the package on our microservices. Creating a repository on Github is impossible for me due to company restrictions.

If I create a folder in `$GOPATH/src/`, I don't know how to include it on docker-compose.yml.

Is it possible to create a folder ("common-utils") then import on the other modules?

```
- user-ms
-- go.mod
- project-ms
-- go.mod
- messages-ms
-- go.mod
- common-utils
-- go.mod
```

Comment: If you have no git server of any kind (In which case I do hope you have other means of having a second copy) you need to use a `replace` directive. For example `replace mymodule => ../mymodule` in your `go.mod` if `mymodule` is next to your module in the same directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your package name with local package.

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/remote_package=../local_package

go mod tidy
```